# Simplifying a class with similar classes inside

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
class Animals
{
    class Cat
    {
        int Rarity
        {
            get { return 32; } 
        } 

        int amount;
        int Amount
        {
            get { return amount; }
            set { amount = value; } 
        }   
    } 

    class Dog
    {
        int Rarity
        {
            get { return 15; } 
        } 

        int amount;
        int Amount
        {
            get { return amount; }
            set { amount = value; } 
        }
    } 

    class Tiger
    {
        int Rarity
        {
            get { return 3; } 
        } 

        int amount;
        int Amount
        {
            get { return amount; }
            set { amount = value; } 
        }
    } 
}
```

How can I simplify this ?

Comment: I'd suggest reading some basic C# and OOP tutorials and use inheritance..

Comment: I'm sry for this code snippet. I can't find a way to put all of this code in code mode...

Comment: I've searched for inheritance but i can't appky this to my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `Animal` base class. You'll probably want to make it `abstract` so the only way to instantiate an `Animal` is by creating a new derived object.

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract int Rarity { get; }  // Abstract properties must be implemented by derived classes
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Then each of your different types of animals can inherit the `Animal` base class. They'll each need to override the abstract `Rarity` property. They'll each have the `Amount` property from the `Animal` class.

```
class Cat : Animal
{
    public override int Rarity => 32;
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public override int Rarity => 15;
}

class Tiger : Animal
{
    public override int Rarity => 3;
}
```

Comment: How can I simplify the other property ? Thx btw

Comment: @ZacBoum It's already simplified. Having `Amount` in the base class means that all of the subclasses automatically have it.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you do some inheritance. Make a class "Animal" that has all those properties.

```
class Animal
{
        int Rarity
        {
            get; 
        } 

        int amount;
        int Amount
        {
            get { return amount; }
            set { amount = value; } 
        }
}
```

Then you can create a class (i.e. Cat) and let it inherit from the class Animal.

```
class Cat : Animal
{

}
```

You can do the same with functions.